# What is my iPad syncing?

Tags: ios, ipad, data-synchronization

This is not the first time I have seen this.  The sync icon is rotating next to the WiFi icon.  Nothing is downloading from the App Store, there are no app or IOS updates available, Mail doesn’t say it’s downloading anything, Maps.me isn’t running and hasn’t been asked to update any maps, etc.  It has been rotating for over an hour, during which it has not been plugged into either charger or Mac.

Comment: Go to Settings > General > iTunes Wi-Fi Sync, what’s being synced?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems to be in a sync to iTunes, but it also says it only does that when plugged in.  Maybe a sync was interrupted a long time ago and I didn’t notice until now?

Comment: Went to the MBP and checked iTunes.  It doesn't show a sync.  Tell it to sync, and it says "looking for iPad" for a long time, then gives up without an error message.  Got iPad and plugged in.  iTunes doesn't start sync automatically.  Canceled Sync on iPad; icon continues to rotate. and iTunes does nothing.  Then "sync now," and no change on either device.  Time for reboot, I guess.

Comment: That’s odd, seems like a confused state, restart iTunes too imo

Comment: Do you have any iCloud services on? It's likely iCloud related since iTunes isn't the culprit.

Comment: Given the symptoms described, it seems likely that iTunes _was_ involved.  To confirm that, it wasn't there after reboot.  If something were syncing to iCloud or OneDrive or DropBox, it would resume after reboot.  (And any changes were not possibly big enough to cause over an hour of syncing.)